# How to boot into Windows 8 from Grub?

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, uefi

I just did a 50GB partition on my laptop thaty initially had windows 8 on it, every time i try booting Windows im getting an "invalid EFI file path" I just ran a boot repair and it gave me this URL: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5684049/

If anyone knows how to help me out id really appreciate it!

Comment: From the "chainloader +1" in your grub.cfg, it doesn't look like you actually did the boot-repair repair.  After the repair, the command will look more like "chainloader (${root})/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi", with an actual EFI path (maybe not the one shown, might be to shim"

Answer (score 0):

It *did* do the boot repair; the entry entitled `Windows UEFI bkpbootmgfw.efi` *should* boot Windows. If it doesn't, I recommend you try the following procedure:

1. Disable Secure Boot in your firmware. Unfortunately, the details of how to do this vary from one computer to another, so I can't be more specific.
2. Use the Boot Repair tool again, but click "Advanced Options," check "Restore EFI Backups," and proceed. This will undo most of Boot Repair's "fixes," which obviously aren't working.
3. In your regular Ubuntu installation (not in a live CD), download and install the Debian package version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)

When you reboot, the result *should* be an ability to boot either Windows or Linux (the latter, most likely, via at least two menu entries, one of which uses GRUB and the other of which is more direct). This procedure works for most people, but for some there are other complications -- unfortunately, subtle differences between EFI implementations, EFI bugs, and bugs in software can cause problems, and you've just got to deal with them on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Disable SecureBoot in your BIOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#SecureBoot)
2. run Boot-Repair --> Advanced Options --> tick `Restore EFI backups` --> Apply. Indicate the new URL that will appear. Reboot and indicate if Windows boots.
3. Run Boot-Repair's `Recommended Repair`, and write on a paper the new URL that will appear.
   Reboot the PC. GRUB will appear. Indicate if Ubuntu and Windows can boot from the GRUB menu.
4. If still not good, please indicate the URL you wrote. Then run Boot-Repair --> Advanced Options --> tick `Restore EFI backups` --> Apply, then install rEFInd's DEB ([direct link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/files/0.6.11/refind_0.6.11-1_amd64.deb/download)), reboot the PC, and indicate what you observe.